# "Энергия ци" — это плеоназм?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, семантика, заимствования, плеоназм

Одно из значений слова "ци" в китайской философии — это "жизненная энергия"; получается, словосочетание "энергия ци" — это плеоназм, достаточно просто "ци"? Например:

*(Энергия) ци течёт по моему телу.*

Comment: Дело в том, что Ци - это не энергия, но при переводе понятия, приходится подбирать что-то, с чем его ассоциировать, вот подобрали слово энергия, получилось энергия Ци. Но Ци - это дословно воздух, газ, эфир(если это что-то вам говорит), а словосочетание "энергия Ци" дает ассоциацию и иллюзию понимания, что-такое Ци, скорее как мем. Ну и используется всё это для популяризации китайской философии. Так что на самом деле не важно, напишите вы энергия или нет - получится не совсем то, что задумывали китайцы.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказал, что энергия в данном случае является родовым словом. В текстах, нацеленных на среднестатистического читателя, видимо, предусмотрительно пояснять, что же такое ци. А вот в эзотерической и философской литературе родовое слово можно и опустить, так как читатель в курсе значения этого термина.
Является ли плеоназмом? Да, конечно. Любое родовое слово — избыточно и всегда образует плеоназм.

Comment: Плеоназм — это вся фраза, не избыточное слово.

Comment: @oleedd отредактировал